# Balanced Random Forest in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I was wondering if there is a implementation of Balanced Random Forests (http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf) in R. They are useful for problems with imbalanced classes. I was also wondering if it is analogous to using the `sampsize` parameter for `randomForest()` in `randomForest`. From what I can tell, there isn't a direct implementation of Balanced Random Forests, but that could be that it is exactly what `sampsize` does.

Comment: I think this is a great question, but asking in the wrong place. It is really a methods question and/or a request for a package recommendation. Both interpretations warrant closure under the SO rules. I'm vote to migrate to CrossValidated.com. Future questions to SO should have code and data.

Comment: I am ok with that, I will keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: After looking at a PPT by the authors of hte package, I'd say that BRF is _exactly_ like using sampsize. I think you need to use Google more aggressively. Also suggest searching for R packages implementing SMOTE.

Comment: Here's a link for the same question on SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171380/implementing-balanced-random-forest-brf-in-r-using-randomforests